# Error al mostrar los datos en un JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Tengo el siguiente error en el `body onload="partida();"` ya que cuando lo ejecuto no trae ningún valor de la base de datos, busque y probe igual con windows.onload pero aun asi no me funciono me aparece

> Uncaught ReferenceError: partida is not defined,

alguna sugerencia que me puedan dar?

```
function partida() {
            <% for (i = 0; i < rut.length; i++) {%>
                rutJS[<%= i%>] = "<%= rut[i]%>";
                edadJS[<%= i%>] = "<%= edad[i]%>";
                sexoJS[<%= i%>] = "<%= sexo[i]%>";
            <%}%>

                document.getElementById("Select1").options[i].value = rutJS[i];
                for (i = 0; i < rutJS.length; i++) {

                    document.getElementById("Select1").options[i].value = rutJS[i];
                    document.getElementById("Select1").options[i].text = rutJS[i];
                }

                document.getElementById("Select2").length = rangoEdad.length;
                for (i = 0; i < rangoEdad.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("Select2").options[i].value = rangoEdad[i];
                    document.getElementById("Select2").options[i].text = rangoEdad[i];
                }

                for (i = 0; i < rangoEdad.length; i++) {
                    if ((i + 20) == edadJS[0])
                        document.getElementById("Select2").selectedIndex = i;
                    if (sexoJS[0] == 1)
                        document.getElementById("sexo").item(0).checked = true;
                    if (sexoJS[0] == 0)
                        document.getElementById("sexo").item(1).checked = true;
                }
```

> Estoy es el html de la etiqueta body

```
<body onload="partida();">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese código compila correctamente? por favor incluye una traza más completa del error, pues ya te señalaron que el código que pusiste está incompleto y el error indica que no hay disponible un método con ese nombre. Lo otro: dónde está puesto el código de ese método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta cerrar la "llave" de la función **partida**

Comment: gracias, y eso que lo revise 5 veces jejeje tenia mucho codigo metido, error capa 8